# Cannot boot up OBS, prints an error

Tags: linux, obs

- Distro: **elementaryOS Ubuntu Linux 16.04**
- Kernel:
  **4.4.0-72-generic**
- OBS version: **18.0.1**

I tried installing OBS via the installation instructions for Ubuntu Linux, but when I tried to run `obs`, I received an error in the provided log. I then tried to compile OBS manually and received the same error message.

```
$ obs

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(obs:12741): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(obs:12741): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(obs:12741): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(obs:12741): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
debug: Found dbus service: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/de-DE.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/de-DE.ini
info: Using preferred locale 'de-DE'
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
info: Processor: 4 logical cores
info: Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
info: Physical Memory: 15975MB Total
info: Kernel Version: Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
info: Distribution: "elementary OS" "0.4"
obs: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libobs.so.0: undefined symbol: XGetXCBConnection
```

After the first failed attempt to install OBS from the PPA they provide, I had to resort to installing it via the general linux installation guide, to no avail. As the guide suggested, I installed the xcb libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libpulse-dev libxcomposite-dev \
                       libxinerama-dev libv4l-dev libudev-dev libfreetype6-dev \
                       libfontconfig-dev qtbase5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libx264-dev \
                       libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
[sudo] password for limeth:
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Hinweis: »libfontconfig1-dev« wird an Stelle von »libfontconfig-dev« gewählt.
libjack-jackd2-dev is already the newest version (1.9.10+20150825git1ed50c92~dfsg-1ubuntu1).
libv4l-dev is already the newest version (1.10.0-1).
libx11-dev is already the newest version (2:1.6.3-1ubuntu2).
libxcb-shm0-dev is already the newest version (1.11.1-1ubuntu1).
libxcb-xinerama0-dev is already the newest version (1.11.1-1ubuntu1).
libxcomposite-dev is already the newest version (1:0.4.4-1).
libxinerama-dev is already the newest version (2:1.1.3-1).
libqt5x11extras5-dev is already the newest version (5.5.1-3build1).
libx264-dev is already the newest version (2:0.148.2643+git5c65704-1).
libcurl4-openssl-dev is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2).
libfontconfig1-dev is already the newest version (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1).
libfreetype6-dev is already the newest version (2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.1).
libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libpulse-dev is already the newest version (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2).
libudev-dev is already the newest version (229-4ubuntu16).
qtbase5-dev is already the newest version (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2).
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  libboost-regex1.58.0 libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-jni linux-headers-4.4.0-42 linux-headers-4.4.0-42-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-43
  linux-headers-4.4.0-43-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-59
  linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-62 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic openjfx switchboard-plug-gcc-bluetooth
Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 20 nicht aktualisiert.
```

I also tried reinstalling them:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | cut -f1 | grep libxcb | xargs sudo apt install --reinstall
```

Didn't help either.

Comment: Although this is video related, you're more likely to get a better answer on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had outdated libraries in the `/usr/local/lib` directory.

I moved them in a backup directory using the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
mkdir bak-libobs
mv libobs* bak-libobs/
```